# Does permuting integers below x with same radical preserve the expression of the Bateman-Horn conjecture?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, permutations

Reading the following link : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman-Horn_conjecture I realized that the quantity  $ N(p) $ doesn't depend so much upon  $ n $ than upon its radical. So let's say that two integers  $ m $ and  $ n $ below  $ x $ are  $ x $-conjugates if and only if  $ rad(m)=rad(n) $ . So that the quantity  $ N(p) $ should be preserved under the action of the group of permutations of  $ x $ -conjugates integers. Among those permutations, some should be field automorphisms and thus preserve the expression of the quantity  $ P(x) $.

So can considering this group shed some light on the Bateman-Horn conjecture ?

Comment: What is the definition of the radical of a number? And what is $n$ and why does $N(p)$ depend on it? You mentioned that some permutations might be field automorphisms, of what field?

Comment: I refer to the linked wikipedia article where it is said that  $ N(p) $ is the number of solutions of  $ f(n)\equiv 0\pmod p $. The radical of an integer  $ n $ is the product of the primes dividing it.

Comment: As for the permutations  $ \sigma $ possibly being field automorphisms, I mean they should verify  $ \sigma(a.b)=\sigma(a).\sigma(b) $ and  $ \sigma(a+b)=\sigma(a)+\sigma(b) $.